# AttributeError: Type Object 'Ned' has no Attribute 'attack'?

Tags: python, class, oop, super, attributeerror

Here's my code:

**Classes:**

```
class Player(object):
"""Base class for the player"""
def __init__(self, name, armour, attack):
    self.name = name
    self.armour = armour
    self.attack = attack
class Ned(Player):
    """The main player"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ned, name="Ned", armour=10, attack=3).__init__()
```

**Line Causing the Issue:**

```
entities.Ned.attack += 3
```

**When I run this, I get:**

```
AttributeError: type object 'Ned' has no attribute 'attack'
```

So I don't understand what's going on here. I imported using `import entities` and then used `entities.Ned...`, so I am fairly sure it's not something to do with file loading. All indentations are correct (this was an answer of two AttributeErrors on this website) and I made sure everything was spelt correctly. Anyone know what might be going on? Any answer I find either doesn't work or is too specific to work in my case. Thanks.

Comment: From what you have, it would appear that `ned` would more naturally be an object of type `Player`, rather than a subclass of `Player`, i.e. you would create ned with `ned = entities.Player('Ned',10,3)`. In any case you would need to instantiate an object of type `Player` (or `Ned` if that is really what you want), and then you can increase the attack attribute of the object.

Comment: @EricAppelt, seems like both you and the other answerer say about the same. Is there any where I can learn the difference and when to use which? A book, video tutorial, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Player` class `__init__` function is not indented correctly. You should add another 4 spaces/\t to the block.

You have a wrong super definition. This is a proper one:

```
super(Ned, self).__init__(name="Ned", armour=10, attack=3)
```

You must create a class object first to use it so you should call it as:

```
ned_object = entities.Ned()
ned_object.attack += 3
```

Comment: The unindented `__init__` was a copying mistake, its not actually like that, but I will fix it in my code. Also, why would I need to create a class object? Is the base class already an object? Lastly, is there anywhere I can learn when to create objects or keep them as a class? Like a book or video about OOP you would recommend? Thank you.

Comment: Just changed my code up, and seems like it worked. But again, what would you recommend to learn some OOP in Python?

Comment: [CLICK](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) is a good start